# Calculate sum of one attribute of a point shapefile that distributed in polygon shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, attribute-table, spatial-statistics

I have two shapefiles, one of them is polygon and other is the point. Each of points have attributes that one of them is population. I want to calculate population size in all of polygons.

How can I do that?

Comment: Try `spatial join` with `Merge Rule`.

Answer (score 1):

The `Spatial Join` tool can sum an attribute from a points layer that fall within polygons.

[image]

Comment: @david, if this answers your question then you can mark this as such.